# some questions for iOS batch push notification

Tags: php, ios, push

I need to send the same push notification to thousands of devices. I can get the tokens from DB.

Here is the example of PHP web service code.

```
public function send($tokens) {
    if (is_array($tokens) && count($tokens) > 0) {
        $body = array('aps' => array('alert' => $content, 'badge' => 0, 'sound' => 'received5.caf'));
        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck5.pem');
        $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
        if (!$fp) {
            print "Failed to connect $token $err $errstrn";
            return;
        }
        print "Connection OK/n";
        $payload = json_encode($body);
        foreach($tokens as $token) {
            $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            print "sending message :" . $payload . "/n";
            fwrite($fp, $msg);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

So, first I get the connection to APNs calling:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
```

Then I package the message in a foreach loop, send the notifications.

And finally, close the notifications.

```
fclose($fp);
```

But it just doesn't work, where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go... Ive added an extra chr(0), as per the API docs. The first chr(0) is the command. The next 2 bytes is the length of the token 0x0020.

```
$msg = chr(0) . chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```